# Using the same WSO2 ESB proxy service for two or more SOAP requests... is it possible?

Tags: soap, proxy, wso2, sequence, wso2-esb

I have deployed some proxy services in WSO2 ESB because I have to ask the endpoint for several responses (dataset), according to different soap action. Every response must be set in a file, so I set an appropriate sequence in the outSequence of the proxy service, and this sequence writes the soap answer into a file. 
In this way i have to deploy a proxy service and a sequence for EVERY soapAction, so i ask: is there a way for deploying a single proxy service for a given web service and using it with several sequences according to the soapaction to perform?
My question was born by the need to implement several scheduled tasks that take  a dataset from an endpoint (webService) and write it into a file, but i don't want to deploy so much proxy service for every kind of dataset I have to request to the web service!
I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily create a diffrent proxies for each and every soapAction. You can utilize the [filter mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Filter+Mediator) in the OutSequence of single proxy and do the header base routing to relevant VFS endpoint.

Comment: I think that's the right way, but i don't know how to choose the values for fill the fields for the filter: i suppose I must choose the content of the regular expression in the answer of the webservice (obviously). If I want to  put the selection on the presence of a specific tag in the answer (for example <MyRequestResult>), what could i do?

Comment: Where is the answer of Jean-Michel??

Comment: I've tried to insert as source "get-property('soapAction')" and as regex the soapaction inserted in the task, but i have an error when i try to end the configuration of the proxy.

Comment: Seems like Jean has removed his answer.

Comment: Isuru's Blog[1] will help you out to understand the functionalities of get property. Please refer to that.
Further you can get the soapAction by get-property('Action'), Since you have more than 2 actions to filtered out, you can use the switch mediator [2]

[1] http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/10/synapse-get-property-function.html
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+2%3A+CBR+with+the+Switch-Case+Mediator+Using+Message+Properties

Comment: Thanks Vanji. I put get-property('Action') in Source and "NomeComune" in Regex (with " ") but when i ask the web service for a response about this soapAction it doesn't run the sequence load in the filter. This is a common web service used for didactical use, it calculates the taxpayer's code of any italian citizen at http://webservices.dotnethell.it/codicefiscale.asmx but i can't obtain any useful response when i use the "NomeComune" soap action. Maybe what i put in the Regex field is wrong?